# How to control mutil daemons processes in ruby?

Tags: ruby, daemon

How to start many processes(will run the same script) by "Daemons gem", and how to stop one of them as I want ?  thanks!

Comment: By the way, I would pass one unique value to the script in command line .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using bluepill or god for this task. Both use daemons internally, and both provide a nice ruby way of defining your processes and monitoring them.